# android:exception in encryption

Tags: android, exception, xml-parsing

I am making an app in which i have to encrypt the data and send it to server and in that case while converting data to int form i am getting number format exception .My code is as follows:

```
 public String encryptData(String key, String s)
    {
        try{
        System.out.println("encrypt");     
   //    byte[] utf8 = data.getBytes("UTF8");
         byte[] fin=s.getBytes();
         System.out.println("encrypt2");
     //   byte[] enc = ecipher.doFinal(fin);
         System.out.println("encrypt3");
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
         System.out.println("1");
         int keyLen = key.length();
      //  int dataLen = Convert.ToInt16(data.length());
         System.out.println("2");
        Integer dataLen=Integer.parseInt(s);  // **This line is giving exception**
        System.out.println("3");
        char chData;
        char chKey;
        char[] data1 = s.toCharArray();
        char[] key1 = key.toCharArray();
        System.out.println("4");
        StringBuilder encryptedData = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < dataLen; i++)
        {
            chData = data1[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < keyLen; j++)
            {
                chKey = key1[j];
                chData = (char)(chData ^ chKey);
            }
            encryptedData.append(chData);
        }
       return (encryptedData.toString());
    }
```

and My xml is :

```
xml="<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>" + "<admin_auth_req><user_name>" +username+ "</user_name>" + "<password>" +PWOrd+ "</password></admin_auth_req>";
```

Exception is:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><admin_auth_req><user_name>newuser</user_name><password>tester</password></admin_auth_req>' as integer


                                 `
```

Comment: int dataLen=Integer.parseInt(s); if you want data length means you can use s.length();

Comment: You are parsing `String s` as integer `Integer dataLen=Integer.parseInt(s)`, so what do you expect to get?

Comment: @PadmaKumar, i have tried int but still all in vain , i am getting same exception

Comment: @Arhimed , see my code again , i have to convert it into integer so that i can apply for loop on that

Comment: Since this turned to be an xml-rasing question: removed `cryptography` tag, added `xml-parsing` tag.

Comment: Probably it should be `int dataLen = data1.length;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are triying to convert a `String` value which is not a number representation into `String`. What you really should do is to find the length of the `String`. So change this line:

```
Integer dataLen=Integer.parseInt(s);
```

to:

```
int dataLen = s.length();
```

Comment: thnks for help and +1 for it and i have accepted your answere

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to parse this string as Integer???
`<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><admin_auth_req><user_name>newuser</user_name><password>tester</password></admin_auth_req>`

What did you expect?

Comment: i want to parse it and send encrypted form to server

Comment: replace Integer dataLen=Integer.parseInt(s); to this  Integer dataLen=Integer.parseInt(s.length());